# Running Android apps on Windows 11 in extended mode directly from the phone via USB cable connection

Tags: applications, google-play-store, accessibility, remote-access, windows-11

I was thinking it would be nice if you could attach a USB cable between an Android system and a PC, and view the whole Android operating system on top of the PC.

You can open, then, apps, ... on the PC, but they run with an extended mode which was developed as part of the app, and downloaded with the app, with due payment, (on the Google play store).

The app, then, has a running mode for the phone, and a running mode on the PC, but lives on the phone (in a single place, with a single download).

Add a bonus, when you're done on the PC (with the advantages of extended screen and keyboard), you can save your data (it saves, automatically, with a scheduled daemon that writes stuff to Android over the USB cable (without saving it to the phone), ...) so you can then just disconnect the phone from the PC when you're done, and take your data with you.

When will this be implemented?

Where is this functionality available?

Will it be added as extra support in future versions of Android (with Windows, for example, support running the Android system as a host over USB, or, at least, making the Android apps available to click on, from the Windows OS desktop taken from the Android home screens, just like when you could view Unix on Windows with X Server XDMCP sessions, there was a Windows program that used to do just that on Windows 98, I forget the name, it was something beginning with X referring to the XFree86 project, it worked like XDM or GSM (the gnome version), but with Windows as the host system for Unix apps).

I have heard that Windows 11, runs Android apps natively (but, I think the functionality I am asking for, where you could download an app from the Google play store and run it directly via a USB cable connection on the PC in "extended mode", would be nice).

Thanks.

Comment: Samsung already has it's DEX mode which provides a full desktop without any PC, you just need to connect the phone to a monitor or TV. For full remote control of a phone via USB from Windows/Linux/MacOS use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy).